# I Want to connect my arduino code sim900 parameters to localhost database. Help me

Tags: php, database, arduino, xampp

I want to connect my arduino code data to php webpage using database. While inserting parameters manually it was successfully done but when connecting arduino code to php webpage it doesn't work I am writing like this

```
SIM900.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"localhost:8012/phpgang/getdata.php?");
```

Setting the httppara, the second parameter is the website you want to access
but it doesn't working.

Anyone can help me in writing in correct form or any other related procedure of connecting it? php code os simple as inserting data through .GET process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` isn't a real server. It's a placeholder name (and IP address) that always refers back to the local system. On the SIM900, this is the SIM900 itself, which is not running your web site.

If you are running your web site on your personal computer, that won't work. You will need to upload and run your web site on a publicly accessible web server to access it from the SIM900.